# How to do a filter in react for a multiple array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function like below 'SHOW_ALL' will return all values that is working correctly. 'SHOW_COMPLETED' & 'SHOW_ACTIVE' is not working as expected.

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  console.log("todos",todos);
  switch (filter) {
    case SHOW_ALL:
      return todos;
    case SHOW_COMPLETED:
      return todos.rowData.filter(item => item.status === 'Completed');
    case SHOW_ACTIVE:
      return todos.rowData.filter(item => item.status === 'Active');
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown filter: " + filter);
  }
};
```

todos have value like below

```
const todos =  {
            columnDefs: [
                {headerName:"Todos",field:"todos"},
                {headerName:"Status",field:"status"}

              ],
              rowData: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    todos: 'Walk the Dog',
                    status: 'Completed',
                },
                {
                    id:1,
                    todos: 'learn Redux',
                    status: 'Active'
                }
              ]
            }
```

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: Your `todos` is actually an object. What do you want to return with `SHOW_COMPLETED` and `SHOW_ACTIVE`? Do you want to return the same `todos` object but with filtered `rowData` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return this (and for `Active` of course): 
`{ ...todos, rowData: todos.rowData.filter(item => item.status === 'Completed')}`

You forgot to return the rest of the `todos` object, a `columnDefs` property.

Comment: No problem, keep it up :)